# Laravel, update the password and then save the old one in a table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

everybody, I need to save old user password in `old_password` in users table

So i did

```
   protected function updatePassword( $user, Request $request)
{
    dd($user);
    $user = User::find( $user->id); // This will find the right user
    $user->old_password = $user->password; // This will save the old password
    $user->password = $request->password;
    $user->save();
}
```

My Route

```
Route::post('/password/reset/{token}',  'Auth\ResetPasswordController@old_passwords');
```

but nothing happens any help

Comment: You want to change the user's password and then save the old password in a table?

Comment: @LucasPiazzi yes

Answer (score 1):

Check your User model it must be like that :

```
    protected $fillable = [
       'old_passwords'
        /*and your other fillable columns*/
    ];
```

Comment: i alredy did it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected function updatePassword($id, $password)
    {
       $user = User::find($id); // This will find the right user
       $user->old_password = $user->password; // This will save the old password
       $user->password = $password;
       $user->save();
    }
```

This function will update the users password according to the form and then save the old one in the `old_password` column

Comment: thanks so much but can you tell me how can i make route for it

Comment: i'm sorry but it's not recognaized by my route

Comment: Route::post('password/reset/',           'Auth\ResetPasswordController@saveOldPassword');

Comment: you already have a form? please show me the form and the update function

Comment: i don't have any form

Comment: just  My Route Route::post('password/reset/',           'Auth\ResetPasswordController@saveOldPassword');

Comment: My Function   protected function saveOldPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user = User::find($user); // This will find the right user
        $user->old_password = $password; // This will save the old password
    }

Comment: thanks so much but i'm working in reset password  by laravel auth so i can't use this url

Comment: you can use the old one, just make sure you're passing the user id

Comment: not working i'm not not sure why or how should i route My Password Save Function in web

Comment: i tried to dd my $user but didn't work and didn't even get emmpty

Comment: you need to send to the function your new password and the user's id, thats it.